# How to update the public IP of AWS EC2 instance in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-route53

I'm running a k8s cluster in AWS and I got the following error after I ran `kubectl get cluster-info`:

```
E0902 13:22:08.516718     897 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://api.kubevpro.quickesh.com/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 203.0.113.123:443: i/o timeout
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 203.0.113.123:443: i/o timeout
```

**What I have tried**

- ran `kops validate cluster --state=s3://ky-bucket-kops --name=kubevpro.quickesh.com` and got the following result:

```
Validating cluster kubevpro.quickesh.com

INSTANCE GROUPS
NAME                ROLE        MACHINETYPE MIN MAX SUBNETS
control-plane-us-east-1a    ControlPlane    t3.medium   1   1   us-east-1a
nodes-us-east-1a        Node        t3.small    1   1   us-east-1a
nodes-us-east-1b        Node        t3.small    1   1   us-east-1b

NODE STATUS
NAME    ROLE    READY

VALIDATION ERRORS
KIND    NAME        MESSAGE
dns apiserver   Validation Failed

The dns-controller Kubernetes deployment has not updated the Kubernetes cluster's API DNS entry to the correct IP address.  The API DNS IP address is the placeholder address that kops creates: 203.0.113.123.  Please wait about 5-10 minutes for a control plane node to start, dns-controller to launch, and DNS to propagate.  The protokube container and dns-controller deployment logs may contain more diagnostic information.  Etcd and the API DNS entries must be updated for a kops Kubernetes cluster to start.

Validation Failed
Error: validation failed: cluster not yet healthy
```

From the anwser for this question: [The dns-controller Kubernetes deployment has not updated the Kubernetes cluster's - AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522497/the-dns-controller-kubernetes-deployment-has-not-updated-the-kubernetes-cluster)
I think the reason might be that KOPS does not update the public IP for EC2 instances after instances restarting. I did use KOPS for creating the cluster, and I did shut down the instance and restarted it.

So how should I update the public IP address manually in Route53? I tried to find it in route53 dashboard but found nothing.

Comment: It is DNS resolver, try ```nslookup api.kubevpro.quickesh.com```. The server is https, ping for what?

Comment: @FranxiHidro I updated the output from `nslookup api.kubevpro.quickesh.com`

Comment: I guess the server-side setup white list IP.